# How to use same intent several times

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

I want to have mood_great intent, several times in my conversations. For example at the beginning, when I ask the user how are they today, and later, when I ask them if they want to continue the conversation(no need to make another intent, mood_great works).

But, when I have mood_great, in the middle of the story, and at the beginning of another rule, it says they are overlapping and I am not able to train the model.

I believe there is a workaround for this, since I am trying to build a long conversation chatbot, and the same intents will be used several times.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This isn't strictly an issue with multiple uses of the same intent, but rather sounds like you have overlapping rules. Rules overlap if they have a shared beginning sequence. If you can share the rules then I can help you figure out why the policy can't distinguish between the two. 

If not, you'll need to figure out yourself. You're looking to distinguish between the two with an action, intent, or certain slots difference. So if you have:

rule X:
- intent A
- action B

you can't have:
rule Y:
- intent A
- action C

but you could have:
rule Z:
- action D
- intent A
- action C

Comment: (beginning sequence here means all the events until the last action)

You could also ask these questions in the Rasa forum, we'd probably be able to better help you there!